# I'm trying to return two largest numbers in an array and I'm getting segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int n, i;
  int arr[n];
  int max1 = 0;
  int max2 = 0;

  // introducing array elements 
  printf ("Enter n: ");
  scanf ("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
  // calculating max1, largest number


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i] >= max1)
    max1 = arr[i];
    }

  printf ("The first maximum is %d\n", max1);


  // calculating max2, iterate the array again


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if ((arr[i] >= max2) && (arr[i] != max1))
            max2 = arr[i];
    }

  printf ("The second max is %d", max2);
}
```

The problem asks me to read an one dimension array and find the two largest numbers in this array. I tried to solve it in a less efficient way, so I will first iterate the entire array in order to find the first maximum, then iterate it again to find the second one.
My error is `segmentation fault (Core dumped)` and I don't understand where I did wrong.

Comment: `int arr[n];` = undefined behavior. `n` has no determinate value there. Move that line *below* the scanf` of `n`.

Comment: What do you think the value of `n` is when the compiler sees this line: `int arr[n];` ??

Comment: Your array `a` has an undefined size, since `n` is undefined at the point of the declaration.  Just move the declaration `int a[n];` to *below* the `scanf` call that sets `n`.

Comment: Thank you! Really stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to set a stack allocated array using a variable at:

```
int arr[n];
```

You are allowed to do this:

```
int arr[10] //or any number
```

Basically the size of the array has to be known at compile time.
You've also never set actually set n to a number.

Edit: This apparently incorrect in modern c you are allowed to do this.

Comment: Variable-sized arrays *are* allowed.  The problem isn't the declaration.  If it were, the code wouldn't even compile.  The problem is that `n` is undefined at the point of the declaration.  The declaration simply needs to be moved down below the `scanf` that sets `n`.

Comment: I thought the size of the array had to be known by the compiler. (I actually only do c++, I don't know if it's the same with c)

Comment: In old versions of C that was true.  In modern ANSI C it is not. One more time:  The code compiles.  That immediately tells you your assumption was incorrect.  In old versions of C that don't support variable-sized arrays, it would be a fatal compilation error.  Try it for yourself.  Just understand that the size of the array is determined by the value of `n` at the point of the declaration.

Comment: Look at the comments on the main post.  They all explain the problem, and in fact OP immediately understood and corrected it.  This answer is just spreading misinformation, which is unfortunate (the person who upvoted it clearly has an incorrect understanding now).

Comment: One thing I don't understand. If you want to allocate memory on the stack (like this array), you'd have to know the amount in compile time, right? If so how is this supposed to work then?

Comment: Of course it doesn't know the amount at compile time.  The size can vary from one call to another.  It dynamically adjusts the stack pointer to make room for the array, once it knows how big it is.  That's really the only way it could work.  When the array goes out of scope, the stack is again adjusted to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int n, i;
  
  int max1 = 0;
  int max2 = 0;
  
  printf ("Enter n: ");
  scanf ("%d", &n);
  int arr[n];

  // introducing array elements 
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
  // calculating max1, largest number


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i] >= max1)
    max1 = arr[i];
    }

  printf ("The first maximum is %d\n", max1);


  // calculating max2, iterate the array again


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if ((arr[i] >= max2) && (arr[i] != max1))
            max2 = arr[i];
    }

  printf ("The second max is %d", max2);
}
```

note this

```
printf ("Enter n: ");
scanf ("%d", &n);
int arr[n];
```

your compiler gives an arbitrary garbage value to n, in your code and that possibly is smaller than the number of iterations you have.

I,however, doubt the working of my code in some classic compilers as they want you to put all the declarations on the top